# Is there any exotic Lie Group homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

We know that there exist exotic smooth structures on Euclidean space on $\mathbb{R}^4$, say. On the other hand, if we require the Lie group $G$ to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a topological group, I suspect (though I can't prove) that $G$ must have the same smooth structure as $\mathbb{R}^n$. But when we simply require that there be a homeomorphism, I can't think of any tool that would be useful to proving that $G$ does not have an exotic smooth structure.

Comment: By the classification of connected abelian Lie groups, if $G$ is abelian and simply connected it is a vector space. If $G$ is homeomorphic to a vector space, then $G$ contains no semisimple factors, so is solvable, and hence is diffeomorphic to a vector space (its Lie algebra).

Comment: To see that $G$ is solvable, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi_decomposition

Comment: There is a wrinkle in my comment: you could have semisimple factors of the universal covering space of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, but the argument goes through with those anyway, as the are diffeomorphic to vector spaces.

Comment: It's more generally true that any continuous group structure on $\mathbf{R}^n$ is smooth for a unique smooth structure on $\mathbf{R}^n$, which is diffeomorphic to the standard one. (Even true with "$\mathbf{R}$-analytic".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [this link](https://books.google.de/books?id=gRTDO-wVhj0C&pg=PA49&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), every continuous homomorphism between Lie groups is smooth, so the isomorphism of topological groups is actually a diffeomorphism. In particular, $G$ has the same smooth structure as $\mathbb R^n$.